# How to push AWS ALB logs from S3 to loggly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, loggly

We have an ALB log enabled and pushing to S3 now we want to push these from S3 to Loggly. Any references or lambda functions?

I have found one document [link](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/loggly/Content/admin/aws-elb.htm) but it supports only classic ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but the link you are referring to shows old way of doing this. According to Loggly blog post:

- [New and improved Amazon S3 ingestion](https://www.loggly.com/blog/improved-amazon-s3-ingestion/)

there is a better way of doing this now, and it also supports ALB:

> Support for logs from **Amazon ALB**, Amazon ELB, and Amazon CloudFront, as well as any uncompressed line-separated text files.

More details is in [Amazon S3 Log Ingestion](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/loggly/Content/admin/s3-ingestion-auto.htm?cshid=loggly_s3-ingestion-auto)